# Qsort в структурах C

Tags: структуры, c

Здравствуйте. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Пытаюсь оседлать функцию qsort() на C. Есть определённые проблемы. Программа быстро закрывается на этапе сортировок и не пойму: успешно ли я реализовал Qsort. Компилятор: MS VS 2012 EE. Посмотрите код. Я знаком с этим языком только 6 недель, в ВУЗе не на шутку торопят процесс, так что осознать всё нормально не успеваю. 
Задача изначально такая: Написать программу, в которой есть структура, содержащая и сортирующая элементы: название книги, автор (имя и фамилия), стоимость.
Код рабочий (без ошибок, выдаваемых компилятором).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>

#define un 250

struct books {char title[un]; char authorFirst[un]; char authorLast[un];  int value; char booksis[un]; };

int QUICKsort_FL(const void *sortI, const void  *sortJ) //реализация функции qsort 
  {
   const struct books *sortI1=(const struct books*) sortI;
   const struct books *sortJ2=(const struct books*) sortJ;
   int t;
   t=strcmp(sortI1->authorLast, sortJ2->authorLast); //сравнили фамилии
   if (t!=0) {return t;} else {return strcmp(sortI1->authorFirst, sortJ2->authorFirst);} //сравнили имена, когда фамилии совпадают

  }

**int QUICKsort_VALUE(const void *sortI, const void  *sortJ) //реализация функции qsort (возрастание), для убывания поменять return на противоположные
  {
   int sortI1=((const struct books *) sortI)->value;
   int sortJ2=((const struct books *) sortJ)->value;

   if (sortI1<sortJ2) {return -1;} else if (sortI1==sortJ2){return 0;} else {return 1;}**

  }

**int QUICKsort_TITLE(const void *sortI, const void  *sortJ) //реализация функции qsort 
  {
   const struct books *sortI1=(const struct books*) sortI;
   const struct books *sortJ2=(const struct books*) sortJ;
   int t;
   t=strcmp(sortI1->title, sortJ2->title); 
   if (t!=0) {return t;}

  }**

int main (void)
  {struct books booksA[un];

   int i,j,a,b,c,sortI, sortJ,*help;

  c=0;

    if (b==2)
      {qsort(booksA, un, sizeof(struct books), QUICKsort_VALUE);    //по возрастанию цены

      for (i=0; i<c; i++)   {printf("%s by %s %s: (rub) %d\n", booksA[i].title, booksA[i].authorFirst, booksA[i].authorLast, booksA[i].value);} ; 
      }
    else if ((b>6)&&(b<1)) {printf("Ne vibraly? Its bad!\n"); return 0;}

    if (b==3)
      {qsort(booksA, un, sizeof(struct books), QUICKsort_FL);  //по автору а-я
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s by %s %s: (rub) %d\n", booksA[i].title, booksA[i].authorFirst, booksA[i].authorLast, booksA[i].value);}; 
      }
    else if ((b>6)&&(b<1)) {printf("Ne vibraly? Its bad!\n"); return 0;}   
       if (b==4)
      {qsort(booksA, un, sizeof(struct books), QUICKsort_TITLE);  //по названию а-я
       for (i=0; i<c; i++)  {printf("%s by %s %s: (rub) %d\n", booksA[i].title, booksA[i].authorFirst, booksA[i].authorLast, booksA[i].value);}; 
      }
    else if ((b>6)&&(b<1)) {printf("Ne vibraly? Its bad!\n"); return 0;}
```

Comment: Ну и простыня! Вы не пробовали локализовать ошибку? Например, уберите ввод и попробуйте задавать данные программно (а то разбираться, где именно проблема, лень).

Comment: Меня интересует лишь реализация Qsort, выполнена ли она верно. Естественно я занимаюсь исправлением ошибок.

Comment: >Я знаком с этим языком только 6 недель, в ВУЗе не на шутку торопят процесс, так что осознать всё нормально не успеваю

@XAegis маленький вам совет - не нужно давить на жалость. Большинство из тех, кто реально может вам тут помочь, вряд ли разделит с вами мнение о тяготах жизни студента по вполне понятным причинам

Comment: Не судите по себе, ни о каких тяготах речь не идёт. Слишком большое значение придаёте этому предложению. Вроде как есть о чём другом поговорить. Эту поправку написал для того, чтобы вы не начали вместо основных вопросов разбирать корректность и формальные стороны.

Comment: @XAegis: давайте я повторюсь: ошибки, если они и есть, погребены под массой кода. Уберите всё ненужное из вопроса, будет гораздо легче восприниматься.

И вы сами легко можете ответить на вопрос, правильна ли сортировка, если _оттестируете_ её на данных, созданных программным путём, чтобы исключить влияние других ошибок.

Comment: >Любезнейший, давайте обойдемся без детского "сам такой". Вам дали совет исключительно из желания помочь, обижаться тут не на что.
Ох да, вы это пишите наверно для поддержания психологического равновесия? Может для вас это и является "советом", но для многих остальных врятли, ибо очень субъективно. А вот то, что вы пишите ниже - уже другое дело.

Comment: Код обновлён.

Comment: @XAegis: Пока вроде вызов `qsort` верный. Убедитесь, что `un` имеет правильное значение. Только вот функция `QUICKsort_VALUE` бессмысленная (какой эффект она гарантирует?) и скорее всего неправильная: сравнивать указатели нельзя, они ж для одного и того же элемента меняются в течение сортировки!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде Вы применяете много "майкрософтспецифичных функций" - `scanf_s`, `gets_s` и другие `*_s`. Но их нужно правильно готовить. К примеру, строка

```
gets_s(booksA[c].authorLast);
```

должна содержать ещё один параметр - длину буфера

```
    gets_s(booksA[c].authorLast, un);
```

Из за того, что этого параметра нет, функция берет его со стека, а там обычно будет мусор. Результат этого как всегда непредсказуем.

Или используйте "небезопасные" по мнению Майкрософта функции.

А ещё лучше - просот перейдите на адекватные компиляторы.

Также, в компараторе для qsort не обязательно возвращать именно `-1`, `0`, `+1`. Там на самом деле важен только знак. Поэтому, конструкции вида

```
if (sortI1<sortJ2) {return -1;} else if (sortI1==sortJ2){return 0;} else {return 1;}
```

заменяются на:

```
return sortI1 - sortJ2;
```

ещё замечено. В функции `QUICKsort_VALUE` сравниваются указатели. Это точно то что нужно?
функция `variants` хотя и спрашивает выбор, но его не дает. Она всегда возвращает 0, а переменную `b` в которую она записывает результат выбора, не будет возможности использовать - она локальная и никак не взаимодействует с другой переменной с таким же именем.

переписанная функция `QUICKsort_VALUE`

```
int QUICKsort_VALUE(const void *sortI, const void  *sortJ) //реализация функции qsort (возрастание), для убывания поменять return на противоположные
  {
   int v1 = ((const struct books*) sortI)->value;
   int v2 = ((const struct books*) sortJ)->value;

   if (v1<v2) {return -1;} else if (v1==v2){return 0;} else {return 1;} 
  }
```

Comment: @KoVadim, действительно 

   return a - b;

пишут часто, но надо отдавать себе отчет, что это не работает с большими числами (из-за переполнения).

Есть какой-то красивый прием (выражение), позволяющий этого избежать, но навскидку не помню...

А безопасно написать так

   return (a < b) ? -1 : (a == b) ? 0 : 1;

У ТС же в `QUICKsort_VALUE()` очевидная ошибка. Он сравнивает адреса, а не значения `value`.

А `QUICKsort_TITLE()` вообще копипаста `QUICKsort_FL()`.

Comment: Очень полезная для меня информация. Не могу никак найти нормальные компиляторы, подскажите хоть один. " функция variants хотя и спрашивает выбор, но его не дает. Она всегда возвращает 0, а переменную b в которую она записывает результат выбора, не будет возможности использовать - она локальная и никак не взаимодействует с другой переменной с таким же именем." с этим уже разобрался, обновлю код.
"заменяются на:

return sortI1 - sortJ2;" пытаюсь писать так, чтобы смысл понимать по ходу написания кода.

Comment: return a - b;

будет работать неверно, если b отрицательное и достаточно большое или a отрицательное. Если я правильно понимаю, то у ТС в этом месте должна была сравниваться цена. Она обычно не бывает отрицательной. Да и достаточно большой вряд ли будет (Если только он не в Зимбабве).

Но в общем случае конечно, лучше так не писать.

Нормальный компилятор - gcc/clang + Linux. или icc, но это на любителя.

Comment: "В функции QUICKsort_VALUE сравниваются указатели. Это точно то что нужно?" Врятли, я не умею пока сравнивать целые значения в структурах по средством Qsort, поэтому VALUE может быть написана вообще не верно. С типом CHAR я хотя бы уверен.

Comment: О, точно, Я Title() так и не изменил, но это пока не важно, ибо она типовая, как FL().

Comment: >переписанная функция QUICKsort_VALUE
Здесь есть небольшая проблема, компилятор требует использования указателя на sortI и sortJ.

Comment: забыл там ещё одни скобочки.

и тут подумалось, что следует заменить

    gets_s( xxx ) 

на

    fgets( xxx, un, stdin)

Comment: А лучше использовать GNU `getline()`

(если винда обязательна, то написать ее аналог).

Comment: Это ли простыня, уважаемый @KoVadim? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на другие сообщения этого автора: не простыни, а пододеяльники с наволочками. Студенту следует научиться, прежде всего, правильно формулировать свои вопросы и минимизировать конкретику. В этом плане согласен с @avp по поводу ма-а-аленьких примерчиков, на которых отрабатывались бы придуманные автором алгоритмы - сам так всегда делаю. Кроме того, получая ответы на свои вопросы, стараюсь не огрызаться на собеседника, так как это "вряТли" (вряд ли) способствовало бы... и т.д.

Comment: @BuilderC

> Кроме того, получая ответы на свои вопросы, стараюсь не огрызаться на собеседника,

м?

Answer (score 2):

[@XAegis](/users/11623/xaegis), примите совет.

Когда изучаете что-то для себя новое (в данном случае `qsort()`), то всегда сначала пишите маленькие примерчики, в которых легко разобраться.

Скажем для qsort и массива струткур минут за 15 можно написать

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat tqs.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct t {int x; char s[10];};

int cmpx (const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  struct t *ap1 = (typeof(ap1))p1, *ap2 = (typeof(ap2))p2;

  return ap1->x - ap2->x;
}

int cmps (const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  struct t *ap1 = (typeof(ap1))p1, *ap2 = (typeof(ap2))p2;

  return strcmp(ap1->s, ap2->s);
}

void print (const char *msg, struct t a[], int n)
{
  puts(msg);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d\t[%s]\n", a[i].x, a[i].s);
}

int 
main ()
{
  struct t a[] = {{1, "a"}, {-1, "x"}};
  int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
  print("source", a, n);
  qsort(a, n, sizeof(a[0]), cmpx);
  print("sort by x", a, n);
  qsort(a, n, sizeof(a[0]), cmps);
  print("sort by s", a, n);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ tqs.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
source
1   [a]
-1  [x]
sort by x
-1  [x]
1   [a]
sort by s
1   [a]
-1  [x]
End
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

И легко понять, что правильно работает, как вызывать и т.п.

А вообще у Вас `struct books` очень уж неэкономично написана. Я бы ее переделал на

```
struct books {
  char *title, *First, *Last, 
  *booksis; // здесь не уверен, т.к. просто не представляю, что это за зверь...
  int value;
};
```

и полность отказался от константного выделения памяти (`#define un`) для полей структуры, перейдя на динамическое распределение памяти.

Я надеюсь о malloc() и strdup() Вы слышали.

Comment: >о malloc() и strdup() Вы слышали.

Примерчики обязательно писать буду. Слышал про функции. Прошу обратить внимание на то, что есть определённые требования аспирантов ВУЗа, конечно не все делают программу в одинаковом виде, свободы очень много, но есть незыблемые требования.

Comment: Работает QUICKsort_FL(), остальные две не работают правильно. Выводят частичную сортировку и кучу всяких значков. Дам скриншот, если нужно.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что введены все данные во все 250 (это Ваша un) элементов массива booksA?

Ну и `QUICKsort_TITLE()` я бы подправил 

    return strcmp(...->title, ...->title):

просто сделал.

Comment: Нет, не все конечно, но вывожу то я лишь то, что заполнял. Понятно, что если я буду выводить на печать все 250 объектов, то там будет пустота (т.е. эти значки). Или я ошибаюсь? (что скорее всего)

Comment: А сортировку запускаете для всех 250-ти

    
    #define un 250
    ....
    qsort(booksA, un, sizeof(struct books), QUICKsort_VALUE);

Вот и ошибки. 

Вам надо в какой-то переменной хранить количество реально введенных книг и использовать ее и для сортировок и для печати.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это результат моего не правильного подхода к изучению, буду находить больше времени.

Comment: @XAegis, главное в этом изучении - самостоятельная писанина. Пишите поначалу все (все велосипеды), вот придет в голову, что можно бы эту штуку посчитать на компе - пишите, пробуйте. 

Времени, конечно, уходит немеряно...